# How to delete records from multiple collection by id in express js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have created three collections,

> family {familyname , _id}
>
> root {rootname familyId _id}
>
> child{childname rootId familyId _id}

Now if I delete family, root, and child should also be deleted

So far, I have tried this but it's not working

```
router.delete("/:familyId", (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.familyId;
  Family.remove({ _id: id })
  Root.remove({ _id: id })
  Child.remove({ _id: id })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
          message: 'deleted',
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: All collection have same `_id`??

Comment: no. root and child has familyid

Comment: should I add Root.remove({ familyId : id }) ?? @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: Yes and also you are not passing any callbacks in your queries they are returning promise so either use async await or callback to resolve it. Just like you did with last query `Child.remove()`

Comment: @BhaktiThakkar, can you tell me a bit more about what your stack? What database are you using? Based on the classes and `remove()` method, it looks like you are using MongoDB, is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the promises returned by the **[`.remove()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove)** method as follows:

```
router.delete("/:familyId", (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.familyId;

    const family = Family.remove({ _id: id });
    const root = Root.remove({ familyId: id });
    const child = Child.remove({ familyId: id });

    Promise.all([family, root, child]).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'deleted',
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```